# hanging ssh processes launched from a script

Tags: bash, ssh, linux-mint

i am creating a few vms through a script. as a part of it, i am changing the names of the vms using ssh. for some reason when i run the below command for three vms it works and for the magic number when creating seven vms, the ssh hangs. can someone please explain the behavior?

part of the script. this script runs concurrently for specified X vms.

```
...
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -R $IP
ssh-keyscan $IP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
SSH="ssh -i $SSH_KEY -o PasswordAuthentication=no"

echo "hostname $hostname && 
    echo HOSTNAME=$hostname >> /etc/sysconfig/network && 
    echo 127.0.0.1 $hostname >> /etc/hosts " | ssh -i $SSH_KEY -o PasswordAuthentication=no root@IP
...
```

non-ending ssh processes

```
rag       2867  2808  0 01:05 pts/5  T  00:00:00 ssh -i ssh_key -o PasswordAuthentication=no root@vm4
rag       2869  2812  0 01:05 pts/5  T  00:00:00 ssh -i ssh_key -o PasswordAuthentication=no root@vm7
rag       2872  2818  0 01:05 pts/5  T  00:00:00 ssh -i ssh_key -o PasswordAuthentication=no root@vm1
rag       2875  2811  0 01:05 pts/5  T  00:00:00 ssh -i ssh_key -o PasswordAuthentication=no root@vm6
rag       2879  2814  0 01:05 pts/5  T  00:00:00 ssh -i ssh_key -o PasswordAuthentication=no root@vm5
rag       2881  2813  0 01:05 pts/5  T  00:00:00 ssh -i ssh_key -o PasswordAuthentication=no root@vm3
rag       2884  2807  0 01:05 pts/5  T  00:00:00 ssh -i ssh_key -o PasswordAuthentication=no root@vm2
```

i got strace on one of the running process.

```
...
--- SIGTTOU (Stopped (tty output)) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigreturn(0x16)                      = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
kill(2867, SIGTTOU)                     = 0
--- SIGTTOU (Stopped (tty output)) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGTTOU (Stopped (tty output)) @ 0 (0) ---
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR)                = 4
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x7fd26e1ef540, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x7fd26e1ef540, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x7fd26e1ef540, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {0x7fd26e1ef540, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x7fd26e1ef540, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x7fd26e1ef540, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {0x7fd26e1ef540, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {0x7fd26e1ef540, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {0x7fd26e1ef540, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fd26cd9d4a0}, 8) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_CONTINUE or TCSETSF, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
...
```

Comment: What is in the `$SSH` variable?

Comment: added expansion of $SSH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a race condition, and looking at your script, I think I see where.

From my understanding, you have a script which contains the following 2 line (among others):

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -R $IP
ssh-keyscan $IP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

And you then launch that script multiple times.

This sequence of events can explain your issue:

1. One of the scripts opens up `~/.ssh/known_hosts` to preform the `ssh-keygen -R` command. At this point the `ssh-keygen` command has the whole file read into memory so it can remove the target line.
2. Another script has just finished performing `ssh-keyscan` and writing the line out to the file.
3. The first script's `ssh-keygen` process (the one from step #1) starts writing out the file, but because it read the file before step #2 finished, the file that it's writing out does not contain the line that step #2 added. So the line from step #2 gets wiped.
4. The second script goes to perform the `ssh`, only the host key isn't in `known_hosts` because of the issue mentioned in step #3. So ssh hangs wanting the user to confirm the key.

*More detail:

Backgrounded programs cannot read from the terminal, attempting to do so results in that program getting sent a SIGTTIN. However in your strace, it shows the program getting a SIGTTOU. Normally background programs can write to the terminal without issue, however OpenSSH explicitly turns on a terminal setting called `tostop` which results in this behavior. Going even further, OpenSSH has a signal handler on SIGTTOU (among others) which results in the OpenSSH code going into an infinite loop until you bring the process into the forground (at which point it can display the prompt, and stop getting signaled).*

How you want to go about solving this is another matter.

- One solution would be to add locking (there is a `flock` utility you can use) and lock the `known_hosts` file before those 2 lines, and then unlock after they're done.
- Another solution would be to add the ssh option `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`. You're already defeating the purpose of the `known_hosts` file with those 2 lines of the script, so you might as well just disable it alltogether.

Comment: Since ssh-keygen creates a new temp file, edits and moves back to known_hosts this creates race condition when multiple entries are removed from known_hosts. i have disabled 'StrictHostKeyChecking' altogether and that solves the problem. thanks for your answer.

Comment: @gilles I reverted your changes but kept a few of them. The SIGTTOU changes you made are not accurate. I was able to duplicate this issue on my system, and my terminal does not have the `tostop` flag set. Something else is going on here.

Comment: on executing `echo cmd&&cmd2 | ssh -o` into one of the vms and when known host entry is not found, ssh is trying to write to the terminal that the host could not be verified. but the ssh is not part of the foreground process group so the terminal signals SIGTTOU. but i don't understand why ssh does not recognize that it does not run in the background; i believe it would have been told so by a signal. also i want to change the ssh behavior where it tries to write to terminal but it can't and then the program hangs. i can only find out on `strace`. is there a way around to perform `echo cmd|ssh`

Comment: @rag not quite sure exactly what it is you're wanting. If you want to run `cmd` on the remote host, you're better off doing `ssh host "cmd"` instead of piping it in. If you want to let ssh write to the TTY while backgrounded, wrap it in a `script` (`script -c 'ssh host "cmd"'`).